# Different versions of vimrc being read

Tags: vimrc, microsoft-windows, filesystem

I have an absurd problem. Honestly, I have a hard time figuring out whether this belongs here or a Windows forum.

Using Vim on Win10, I've changed my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc` from the awful default that came with the installation to my own. For simplicity's sake, let's say the file was

```
" _vimrc (default)
colorscheme blue
```

and I changed it to

```
" _vimrc (custom)
colorscheme desert
```

Now, when I run `vim` in cmd or powershell, the colorscheme is "desert", and `:e C:\Program\ Files\ (x86)\Vim\_vimrc` opens the custom file as I would expect. But here's where it gets weird: If I try to use the file from any other program (`notepad`, `dir`, `cat`, `gvim`), it's still the default file, and it's marked as read-only. And when running `gvim`, it uses the "blue" colorscheme.

My first thought was that vim was working on some temporary file, but the changed file persists over program restarts and even a reboot. Is there two files by the same name? How does Vim load different files than gVim?

The output of `:scriptnames` has the exact same first line in both Vim and gVim, "`C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\_vimrc`".

Comment: I don't know where you problem comes from and I can't do test on a windows machine right now, but I can say that you shouldn't change the system vimrc, instead you should create one in your home directory (something like `C:\User\Gustaphe\_vimrc` I believe) that will prevent a lot of troubles related to permissions and this kind of stuff. See [`:h _vimrc`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/starting.txt.html#_vimrc) for the places where you can put your vimrc.

Comment: That had other complications, mostly related to opaque network setup, but I guess it works out for now. Here's to hoping I can manage to forget the fact that there is a ghost file somewhere on my system...

Comment: Actually that's the right way to go, it's better to debug problem in your user space than in system wide environment.

Comment: I wonder if this is related to Windows 32-bit emulation. Depending on whether you're running 32 or 64 bit binary you'll see different contents of some system directories (e.g. \windows\system32). I didn't think the "Program Files" dirs were affected but the behavior you describe smacks of the same thing. Do you see any pattern when comparing behavior of 32-bit programs vs 64-bit? Oh, and you're sure you installed 32-bit Vim (into "Program Files (x86)")?

Comment: Just found this question, and the answer there seems to apply here too. I hate Windows sometimes.
https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3205/contents-of-vimrc-file-depend-on-how-it-is-opened?rq=1

Comment: Ah, that seems even more likely. (The file redirect mechanism sounds very similar to the one used with 32-bit emulation.)

Comment: Moral of the story: never edit files under windows system dirs unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: Moral of the story: Don't use Windows if you can at all avoid it.

Comment: Modern windows is actually fantastic in many ways. While it often is, sometimes *nix isn't the right tool for the job. (Don't make me laugh talking about Macs...novelty items. ;)